# Spark: best way to identify each element in a RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to identify each element of an RDD with an unique id because I have to save, for each of them, a list of their k nearest neighbors. And then, I would like to generate an output like this:

id |  id_neighbor1 | id_neighbor2 | ... | id_neighbork

To do so, I've been reading about the transformations called `.zipWithIndex()` and `.zipWithUniqueID()`, but in the documentation says:

> The index assigned to each element is therefore not guaranteed, and
>   may even change if the RDD is reevaluated.

So, I am pretty sure I cannot use this for what I want, am I right? So, another way to apply my own id would be this:

```
myRdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
  (partID, iterator) => iterator.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (labeledPoint, neighID) => (partID + "," + neighID, labeledPoint)
  },
  preservesPartitioning = true)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to use [`monotonically_increasing_id()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#monotonically_increasing_id--) ?

Comment: you can use any hash generation algorithm which you want to generate the hash of your elements and use that hash as an id.

Comment: @Antot  Yes, I've tried using that and it worked, but I've been making some tests in a local cluster and, surpriselly,  my solution is faster than yours. I have to check the same in the standalone cluster...